In postgres can I efficiently use an indexed jsonb field to perform a Where IN array query?
I have the following query
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = """
        select mt.id
         from my_table mt 
        where mt.data -> 'indexedId' = cast('"' || :stringValue || '"' as jsonb)
    """
)
fun findByIndexedId(@Param("stringValue") stringValue: String): Long?

where mt.data is a jsonb column and mt.data->'indexedId' is a simple string value and an index was created for this field. This query works fast as expected.
Now, I need to query for rows in which mt.data->'indexedId' is in a collection of values, the best I could come up with was :
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = """
        select mt.id
         from my_table mt
        where jsonb_extract_path_text(mt.data,'indexedId') in :stringValues
    """
)
fun findByIndexedIdIn(@Param("stringValues") stringValues: Collection<String>): Long?

Although this works it is quite slow. I assume this is because the extract path function prevents the query from making use of the existing index in indexedId. Therefore my question is whether there is an alternative more efficient query that finds all rows whose indexedId are in the provided collection?
Thank you for your attention

If the index is created on (data -> 'indexedId'), it cannot be used for the expression in your query. You must use the indexed expression in the query.

Offtopic: Not a Java programmer myself, but is this string concatenation in your first piece of SQL safe from SQL injection? Normally you would use a place holder in your SQL.
